# Proof about less than

Tags: logic, coq

I'm trying to prove some theorems about `less_than` in Coq. I'm
using this inductive definition:

```
Inductive less_than : nat->nat->Prop :=
   | lt1 : forall a, less_than O (S a)
   | lt2 : forall a b, less_than a b -> less_than a (S b)
   | lt3 : forall a b, less_than a b -> less_than (S a) (S b).
```

and I always end up needing to show the inverse of lt3,

```
Lemma inv_lt3, forall a b, less_than (S a) (S b) -> less_than a b.
Proof.
   ???
```

I'm stuck, and would be very grateful if someone have some hints on how to proceed.

(Is there something wrong with my inductive definition of `less_than`?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing, your definition of `less_than` is a bit unfortunate in the sense that the second constructor is redundant. You should consider switching to the simpler:

```
Inductive less_than : nat -> nat -> Prop :=
| ltO : forall a, less_than O (S a)
| ltS : forall a b, less_than a b -> less_than (S a) (S b)
.
```

The inversion would then match coq's inversion, making your proof trivial:

```
Lemma inv_ltS: forall a b, less_than (S a) (S b) -> less_than a b.
Proof. now inversion 1. Qed.
```

The second clause was redundant because, for every pair `(a, b)` st. you want a proof of `less_than a b`, you can always apply `lt3` `a` times and then apply `lt1`. Your `lt2` is in fact a consequence of the two other constructors:

```
Ltac inv H := inversion H; subst; clear H; try tauto.

(* there is probably an easier way to do that? *)
Lemma lt2 : forall a b, less_than a b -> less_than a (S b).
Proof.
  intros a b. revert a. induction b; intros.
  inv H.
  inv H.
  apply ltO.
  apply ltS. now apply IHb.
Qed.
```

---

Now if you really wish to keep your particular definition, here is how you could have attempted the proof:

```
Lemma inv_lt: forall a b, less_than (S a) (S b) -> less_than a b.
Proof.
  induction b; intros.
  inv H. inv H2.
  inv H. apply lt2. now apply IHb.
Qed.
```